# Can I LOAD DATA with ugly data that has escape characters and quotes?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have two records for example like this

```
11,avec myName à EX,Ex,0,2021-06-25
22,"andone \"ttt\"",Ex,0,2021-06-25
```

I am trying to load this into a table with MySQL with load data, and every time I try it, the quotes get cut off, or the back spaces don't show up.

I need to know if this is even possible. Can those two records go into a table and look exactly like they are in the CSV file?

I am using MySQL and trying

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'example.csv' INTO TABLE example;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ENCLOSED BY` and `ESCAPED BY` options.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'example.csv' 
INTO TABLE example
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ESCAPED BY '\\';
```

Comment: thanks that seems to have loaded everything into the first column in the table, do i need to map somehow?

Comment: @TWF Add `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'example.csv' INTO TABLE example
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY  ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3.col4,col5);
```

In mysql 8 this will get you an error please read

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-file-location

Windws uses `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`

if the file comes from  a linux system use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

it os hard to tell without seeing the file what parameters would help exactly so you should try some variants out`.

also a editor with hexfile capability helps in such cases to analyse the struicture

Comment: You can't tell from the sample whether the lines are terminated by `\n` or `\r\n`.

Comment: lines in windows are ende by CR LF carriqage return linefeed, Linux ony uses \n, you can chck in an editor with hex values what is at the end of every line